# Relationing tables in postresql

Tags: postgresql, flyway

I want to make some relations in my postgresql database.

My script looks like this:

```
create table anomaly_analysis
(
    id bigserial not null,
    chart_id bigserial constraint charts_pk references charts id not null,
    analysis_date date not null,
    primary key (id)
);

create table anomaly_analysis_data_points
(
    anomaly_analysis_id bigserial 
         constraint anomaly_analysis_pk
             references anomaly_analysis id not null,
    data_point_id bigserial 
         constraint charts_pk 
             references charts id not null
);

alter table data_series
   add column isAnomaly boolean;
```

I want to add foreign key in first table, it will be referencing table charts, on field id. Also in the second table I want to add foreign key, that's going to reference on table I create above, field anomaly_analysis_id on id of anomaly_analysis, and chart_id on table charts and field id.

I tried with this query (it's an example for one line):

```
chart_id bigserial constraint charts_pk foreign key (charts_id )references charts not null
```

But it also didn't worked for me. I tried many similar combination, I was reading documentation and other sites, but it did not worked. What should i do to make my script correct?

**EDIT**

I forgot to add logs. The database is being serviced with flyway.
The exception that I receive is:

```
SQL State  : 42601
Error Code : 0
Message    : ERROR: syntax error at or near "id"
Position: 121
Location   : db/migration /V1.1.15__add_anomaly_analysis_tables.sql (/mypath/V1.1.15__add_anomaly_analysis_tables.sql)
Line       : 1
Statement  : create table anomaly_analysis(
   id bigserial not null,
   chart_id bigserial constraint charts_pk references charts id not null,
   analysis_date date not null,
   primary key (id)
)
```

Comment: You should not use a serial as an FK column. It should be an **integer**, pointing to a serial.

Comment: But other columns in my project are working with type of big serial as fk, the thing that makes me wonder is that other tables with simillar scrips are working fine, just this one crashes during initialization.

Comment: A serial is an integer with a default value supplied by a function. a FK is a set of columns referring to a set of columns in another table. Setting a FK to some value provided by a generator function makes no sense. The generator function knows nothing about the other table.

Comment: `chart_id bigint constraint charts_pk references charts (id) not null` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html

Comment: So i just need to change type of columns that I create, to make my table works right?

Comment: Yes, and you should put parentheses around the foreign column name(s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You should **not** use a `serial` as a FK column. It should be an `integer`, *pointing* to a serial.
- The syntax for FKs needs parentheses: `.. REFERENCING table_name (column, column,...)`
- the `anomaly_analysis` table appears to be a *junction* table, implementing an n-m relation. It certainly will need an index, or even two indices.
- The (sub) syntax for `CREATE TABLE ...` is huge. see  the fine [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html)

You probably want this:

---

```
CREATE TABLE charts( 
        id bigserial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        );

CREATE TABLE anomaly_analysis(
   id bigserial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
   , chart_id bigint not null
         CONSTRAINT charts_fk REFERENCES charts (id)
   , analysis_date date NOT NULL
   );

CREATE TABLE anomaly_analysis_data_points(
   anomaly_analysis_id bigint NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT anomaly_analysis_pk REFERENCES anomaly_analysis(id)
   , data_point_id bigint NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT charts_fk REFERENCES charts(id)
-- , PRIMARY KEY (anomaly_analysis_id,data_point_id) -- ?? Will force an index to be created
-- , UNIQUE (data_point_id, anomaly_analysis_id) -- Will force an index to be created, too
   );

-- alter table data_series add column isAnomaly boolean; -- huh?
```

Comment: I corrected it myself earlier following your instructions, thanks for writing answer so I can upvote you and close the question